# Find the limit of $(1^7 + 2^7 + .......+ n^7)^{1/n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The question tells me find the limit of $(1^7 + 2^7 + .......+ n^7)^{1/n}$.

I thought that I would use an idea similar to the one given below:

> **Exercise 1.8.4.** $a_n=\sqrt[n]n.$
>
> **Solution.** If we take $b=\sqrt[n]n$ and apply $(1.14)$, we obtain $$n>\frac{n(n-1)}2(\sqrt[n]n-1)^2.$$ It follows that $$0<\sqrt[n]n-1<\sqrt{\frac2{n-1}}\to0,$$ so $\lim{\sqrt[n]n}=1$.

[(Image that replaced the text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTIFp.png)

but with $b = n^{14/n}$ and using the $14^{\text{th}}$ term of the binomial theorem which is $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-13)}{14!} (n^{14/n} - 1)^{14}$$ but I got stucked.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Use the fact that the expression you have is at most $(n*n^7)^{1/n}$ and at least $(n^7)^{1/n}$ and then use the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: why it is at most $n * n^7$ why are you neglecting the $7^{th}$ power of each number before the n^7? why are you sure that their values will be less n? @Marco

Comment: @hopefully pairwise comparisons $1\leq n, 2\leq n, \cdots$ by making estimate that all of the n of them are n we can sum them up to $n\cdot n^7$, the $n^7$ bound you get by estimating all the other terms except the biggest to 0. This is only valid since all the functions are monotonically increasing in $n$

Comment: yeah thank you so much @mathreadler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $n^{\frac{8}{n}} = (n^{\frac{1}{n}})^{8} \to 1^{8}=1$.

Now $ 1^{1/n} \leq (1+\ldots+n^7)^{1/n} \leq (n^8)^{1/n}$.

Since both limits are $1$, we have that our limit is $1$.

Comment: why it is at most $n * n^7$ why are you neglecting the $7^{th}$ power of each number before the n^7? why are you sure that their values will be less n?

Comment: Well, there are $n$ numbers and each of them is at most $n^7$.

Comment: perfect! thank u :)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1^{7} + 2^{7} + \cdots + n^{7}}^{1/n}} =
\exp\pars{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{7}} \over n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n + 1}k^{7}} -
\ln\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{7}} \over \pars{n + 1} - n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln\pars{1 + {\bracks{n + 1}^{7} \over \sum_{k = 1}^{n + 1}k^{7}}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\ln\pars{1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}{\bracks{n + 2}^{7} - \bracks{n + 1}^{7} \over \bracks{n + 2}^{7}}}} = \exp\pars{\ln\pars{1}} = \bbx{1}
\end{align}

> We were using the
>   [Stolz-Ces$\mrm{\grave{a}}$ro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) in the last two lines.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming that you could be interested by more than the limit itself.*

Considering [Faulhaber polynomials](https://en.wkipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n i^7=\frac {a^2(6a^2-4a+1)} 3 \qquad \text{where} \qquad a=\frac 12 n (n+1)$$ you can write
$$S_n=\frac{n^8}8 \left(1+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{14}{3 n^2}-\frac{7}{3 n^4}+\frac{2}{3
   n^6} \right)$$
$$\log(S_n)=\log\left(\frac{n^8}8\right)+\log \left(1+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{14}{3 n^2}-\frac{7}{3 n^4}+\frac{2}{3
   n^6} \right)$$ Now, using Taylor expansion
$$\log(S_n)=\left(8 \log \left({n}\right)-\log (8)\right)+\frac{4}{n}-\frac{10}{3
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

$$\frac 1 n \log(S_n)=\frac{8 \log \left({n}\right)-\log (8) }n+\frac{4}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Using Taylor again
$$S_n^{\frac 1n}=e^{\frac 1 n \log(S_n)}=1+\frac{8 \log \left({n}\right)-\log (8) }n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.